# PL SQL Create table with concatenated fields

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I need to create a table and add certain characters to each field.
I need each field to be enclosed by "" and I also need the fields to be pipe delimited |
My code is as follows

```
Begin
execute immediate 'Create Table dbo.Temp_Weekly_Export_File as
Select ''"'' ||A.unique_id || ''"|'' as unique_id,
   ''"'' ||A.name || ''"|'' as name,
   ''"'' ||A.alt_name || ''"|'' as alt_name,
   ''"'' ||A.entity_type || ''"|'' as entity_type, 
   ''"'' ||A.party_type || ''"|'' as party_type,
   ''"'' ||A.reference_# || ''"|'' as reference_#, 
   ''"'' ||A.addr1 || ''"|'' as addr1 ,
   ''"'' ||A.addr2 || ''"|'' as addr2,
   ''"'' ||A.addr3 || ''"|'' as addr3,
   ''"'' ||A.town || ''"|'' as town,
   ''"'' ||A.county || ''"|'' as county,
   ''"'' ||A.postcode || ''"|'' as postcode, 
   ''"'' ||A.country || ''"|'' as country,
   ''"'' ||A.alt_address1 || ''"|'' as alt_address1, 
   ''"'' ||A.alt_address2 || ''"|'' as alt_address2,
   ''"'' ||A.alt_address3|| ''"|'' as alt_address3, 
   ''"'' ||A.alt_town || ''"|'' as alt_town,
   ''"'' ||A.alt_county || ''"|'' as alt_county, 
   ''"'' ||A.alt_post_code || ''"|'' as alt_post_code,
   ''"'' ||A.alt_country || ''"|'' as alt_country, 
   ''"'' ||A.nationality || ''"|'' as nationality,
   ''"'' ||A.dob || ''"|'' as dob,
   ''"'' ||A.individual_id || ''"|'' as individual_id,
   ''"'' ||A.individual_id_type || ''"|'' as individual_id_type ,
   ''"'' ||A.country_of_registration|| ''"|'' as country_of_registration, 
   ''"'' ||A.company_id || ''"|'' as company_id,
   ''"'' ||A.company_id_type || ''"|'' as company_id_type  ,
   ''"'' ||A.source_country || ''"|'' as source_country,
   ''"'' ||A.source_system || ''"|'' as source_system,
   ''"'' ||A.transaction_type|| ''"|'' as transaction_type
   From dbo.Temp_Weekly_Export A';
   End;
```

I am getting the following error message 10:22:26  ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected

Comment: Why do you use all the double quotes `"`? Do you really think it makes sense to create table dynamically? What is your intention?

Comment: Why are you using dynamic SQL for this?

Comment: It is part of a much larger script. I am creating it dynamically as I need a procedure to count up and highlight duplicate fields in certain columns.

Comment: Double quotes are needed in each field. The two single quotes are to allow the code to run

Comment: You should make a simple select and surround `"` and `|` in this query.

Comment: What do you mean by surround " and |

Comment: What do you mean with "pipe delimited |"? Do you need to create a table with a single column, containing the concatenation af all the columns in the source table? or do you need a table with the same number of columns of the source table?

Comment: I need a table where all values are surround by " and end with | Example: "111"|

Comment: How many columns in the result table? A single column or the same number of columns than the source table?

Comment: The same number of columns as the source table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without need to explicitly write all the column names, you may use the following

**Setup:**

```
create table source(colA, colB, colC) as (
    select 1, 2, 3 from dual union all
    select 4, 5, 6 from dual
)
```

The plsql:

```
declare
    vSQL varchar2(1000);
begin

    select 'select ' || rtrim(listagg('''"''||' || column_name || '||''"|'' as ' || column_name || ',') within group ( order by column_name), ',') || ' from ' || table_name
    into vSQL
    from user_tab_columns
    where table_name = 'SOURCE'          
    group by table_name;
    --
    vSQL := 'create table target as ' || vSQL;
    execute immediate vSQL;
end;
```

The result:

```
SQL> select * from target;

COLA       COLB       COLC
---------- ---------- ----------
"1"|       "2"|       "3"|
"4"|       "5"|       "6"|
```

Answer (score 1):

See example below. You just need to additional `'` around `"`

```
declare
var varchar2(2000);
BEGIN

 var:= 'Create  Table Temp_Weekly_Export_File as
        Select ''"'' ||UNIQUE_ID|| ''"|'' as unique_id,
         ''"'' ||NAME || ''"|'' as name
         From Test ';

   --dbms_output.put_line(var);
     EXECUTE IMMEDIATE var;

END;
```

Demo:

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE  TEST
(
  UNIQUE_ID  VARCHAR2(103 CHAR),
  NAME       VARCHAR2(103 CHAR)
);

Table created.

SQL> declare
var varchar2(2000);
BEGIN

 var:= 'Create  Table Temp_Weekly_Export_File as
        Select ''"'' ||UNIQUE_ID|| ''"|'' as unique_id,
         ''"'' ||NAME || ''"|'' as name
         From Test ';

    --dbms_output.put_line(var);
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE var;

END;  
  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> select * from Temp_Weekly_Export_File;

no rows selected
```

Comment: Thanks, I can't run the declare statement as sql ? Does this need to be put into my script?

Comment: Just declare the variable in your procedure

Comment: I added it into my script and it compiles, however I am getting no result file being generated?

Comment: Well there will not be any file which will be generated but a table will be created. Check if table is being created or not. Check my demo

Answer (score 0):

I like ALEKSEJ's answer. Whenever I have to use double quotes, I substitute the Q quote syntax. I find it easier to read and to make changes. I no longer have to double up the quotes. Here is Alek's solution using Q quotes:

```
BEGIN
      SELECT    'select '
             || RTRIM (
                    LISTAGG (q'['"' ||]' ||  column_name || q'[||'"|' as ]' || column_name || ',')
                        WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY column_name)
                  , ','
                )
             || ' from '
             || table_name
        INTO vsql
        FROM user_tab_columns
       WHERE table_name = 'SOURCE'
    GROUP BY table_name;

    --
    vsql   := 'create table target as ' || vsql;

    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE vsql;
END;
```

Q quotes can be embraced with the paired symbols

> q'[ ]', q'{ }', q'< >', or q'( )'